# Javascript JScrollPane on Div without P Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I'm using jsFiddle to get the desired result, though I'm failing.

This is the link:   [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7b2/68/)

I want the div without the p tags to have a vertical scroll bar as well! Though it wouldn't work.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- this works -->
<div class="scroll-pane other">
    <p>dslkfja;dasfj;asdkfj</p>
    <p>d;aslkfjasd;lfkdas;kfj</p>
    <p>d;aslkfjasd;lfkdas;kfj</p>
    <p>d;aslkfjasd;lfkdas;kfj</p>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</div>

<!-- this does NOT work -->
<div class="scroll-pane other">
    asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    <!-- and so on... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your code is working already

but you make a single string "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" in your js fiddle so it not set breaks in small string then it work
```

i set a demo see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/Rq7b2/69/)

Comment: sadly it does not work
EDIT: It does thanks to the p tag, thanks mate